# google cloud storage: find size of sub-folders with gsutil du?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, du, google-cloud-storage

I want to find the size of my sub-folders at the first depth in Google Cloud Storage. There is the function `gsutil du`, that is quite similar to `du`, but with some differences.

I am not able to just show the size of the sub-folders at the first depth. Using traditional du, I could use (from this [stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185764/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-directory-on-the-command-line)):

```
du -h --max-depth=1
du -sh -- *
```

What is the equivalent with `gsutil du`? Doing `gsutil du -h gs://bucket_name/*` prints info for all sub-folders (many depths) while `gsutil du -sh gs://bucket_name/*` shows only grand total.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder_name | xargs -I{} gsutil du -sh  {}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: are you sure about the `-l` flag? It seems to produce too much output which will induce `du` into error with message like _InvalidUrlError: Unrecognized scheme "48  2023-06-04t13:02:09z  gs"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no --max-depth support in gsutil du. You could write a script that lists the first-level folder names, and then iterate over those folders and run `gsutil ls -l $folder/*`

Comment: yes, I was thinking an alternative would be something like `gsutil ls |` but I am not fluent enough in `xargs` and colleagues :-(